# Eclipse IDE for Scientific Computing for C++ on windows

Tags: eclipse, windows-10, openmpi, scientific-computing, mpic++

I have installed the latest version of Eclipse IDE for scientific computing 2020-12. I am trying to run an MPI c++ project but I get this error :

> Program "mpic++" not found in PATH

I have already installed Microsoft MPI on my system but now I do not know how should I get mpic++ on windows10. I downloaded it from [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.1/)  but no idea how to open `src.rpm` file !

Comment: RPM stands for Red Hat Package Manager, you won't be able t open it under windows.

Comment: @geebert Thanks! so, it seems there is no way to have mpic++ on windows right?

Comment: this might be useful to you: https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft-MPI/blob/master/examples/helloworld/Run_MPIHelloWorld.md I don't have a windows machine though, so I can't check what compiler you should use under windos or how your path variable should be set up.